# Reset button in DataTables Server Side mode to show the original table data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have DataTables 1.10.15 set up in Server Side mode.

The ajax script to produce the data for the table is triggered when various inputs are completed by using jquery's `keyup` and `change` methods.

I want to implement a button to reset the table to it's original (first time the page is loaded, before any search/sorting) state.

So I implemented this which means when a button (`#resetSearch`) is clicked it clears all the search input fields and then redraws the table:

```
$('#resetSearch').click(function(){
    $(':input','#primarySearch')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');

    myTable.draw();
});
```

The variable `myTable` is a reference to DataTables:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({ });
```

The problem is that although it clears all my search inputs, it doesn't reset the `sort` and `order` inputs which are within the table. Therefore if I did a sort descending on column 2, and then pressed `#resetSearch`, it will give all the results in descending order by column 2 - because there's no code there to reset that to ascending column 0.

I don't understand how to target the `sort` or `order` inputs such that I could overwrite them and make this work.

Please can someone help?

Comment: Does this help? [stackoverflow.com/questions/33212389/restore-original-sort-order-with-jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212389/restore-original-sort-order-with-jquery-datatables)

Comment: @markpsmith it's all deprecated. Every link or SO post I'm coming across is for older versions of DataTables, or ones where they're not using Server Side mode

Comment: Have you tried `$('#myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Datatables already has handler for class/selector '.filter-cancel' for your issue.

Put button or link with class 'filter-cancel' inside to your table (in  for example) and test by clicking on it. It will reloads your data by default and resets all filters.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure where you've got `.filter-cancel` from as it's not mentioned in the documentation? There *was* a `fnFilterClear` method (https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFilterClear) but that's deprecated.