# How do you manipulate DataTables ajax if you've assigned it to a variable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

DataTables 1.10.15

My DataTable is assigned to a variable:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({ });
```

I want to modify some of the data sent in the ajax request, then redraw the table, when pressing a button in my application. Documentation for the ajax methods are here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

When I tried

```
myTable.({ 'data' : {'foo': 'bar'} }).draw();
```

It gives a console error:

**Uncaught TypeError: myTable is not a function**

But you can't reinitialise DataTables, so I can't do something like this either:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({ 'data' : {'foo': 'bar'} });
```

The background to this is that [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233383/reset-button-in-datatables-server-side-mode-to-show-the-original-table-data) about a reset button for the table when using Server Side mode which doesn't have an answer here on Stackoverflow or the DataTables forum. So I was planning to try and manipulate the ajax request to reset the `dir` and `column` parameters by passing it as ajax data. But I can't see how to manipulate the request. A lot of things with DataTables seem un-necessarily complex - I don't think I should even have to be doing what I'm asking here, but there's no easy way to reset the data to its original state because it retains the `dir` and `column` parameters in the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is correct, but you need to do this as part of the initialisation code, not afterwards.

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data.json",
        "data": {
            "reset_sort": $('#myhiddenfield').val()
        }
      }
});
```

I've used code from the documentation - every time the table is drawn, the `reset_sort` parameter will be passed as part of the datatable server-side request.  In the situation you describe, you'd probably pass a flag to tell the serverside code to reset the sort column and direction parameters.

So for example, say you have hidden field `id="myhiddenfield"` and a button `id="mybutton"`, and you have a click event for the button in which you want to refresh the table and pass a parameter in the ajax request which tells the server-side code that you want to reset the sorting.

This is the hidden field in the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="false" id="myhiddenfield" />
```

This is the javascript button click event:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#myhiddenfield').val('true');
   myTable.draw();
   $('#myhiddenfield').val('false');
}
```

So normal datatable functionality (sorting, paging etc) will pass `reset_sort = false` in the request because the default value of the hidden field is `false`.

However when we click the button, we update the hidden field to `true` before we call `draw()`, so now `reset_sort = true` will be passed in to the server-side code.

Afterwards we reset the hidden field back to its default value.

Comment: Thanks. I've already got it set up in a similar way and am passing my own form data with the ajax method. The trouble is, that's all there on page load. I need to modify the request IF the user presses a certain button (to reset the table). Have a look at the linked question in my original post and you'll see what I'm trying to do. I get how to make the initial ajax request - it's modifying it dynamically I'm struggling with.

Comment: in that example above, the code is there on page load...but what if I want to dynamically change `user_id: 451` to say `user_id: 690`... then trigger the ajax? I don't understand how to manipulate the things in `data:` dynamically and then submit the ajax request.

Comment: You would manipulate `user_id` by usng jquery to get the value from somewhere. For example in your button click, you would assign a value to a hidden field before you call `draw()`.  Then when the datatable reloads, it will get the value of whatever you've set dynamically.

Comment: it's the setting of it that I can't figure out! I have the data available, but how do I pass it ****into `var myTable`'s ajax method****? That's the bit I can't figure out! I understand the principle of all you said.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more detail - I hope that's clearer!

Answer (score -1):

Try this  one and get data from server in this format

data=[{ "S.no": "Tiger Nixon", "Name": "System Architect", "Job": "$3,120" },
         {"S.no": "Tiger Nixon", "Name": "System Architect", "Job": "$3,120" }];

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                     columns:[{data: 'S.no'}, {data: "Name"},{data:"Job"}] 
                    });

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {  
                 myTable.row.add(data).draw();
                }
        });
```

Comment: It's about manipulating the data *before* the ajax request is made

Comment: it's simple just give data to the myTable.row.add([ some json array ]).draw

Comment: Right, except you're doing that in the `success` callback which is AFTER the ajax request has been made. We're talking about modifying what gets sent in the ajax BEFORE the request is made.